# Intellij not uploading all files to github, only .java files

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm new to github and intellij integrations, but had no problem with Eclipse (inside the gui).

I'm trying to share my project on github through intellij, but it is only uploading the .java files, not the pom.xml or resource files outside of the main directory.

How does one have it include the full directory/file structure of the project, not just one directory?

Comment: Check if you have a .gitignore.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/adding-files-to-version-control.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html#add-new-files

Comment: I know I must be daft, but no such option is appearing. Please see screenshot.

http://imgur.com/a/8vmsW